# Flask-migrate seems to run outdated version of python

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm new to flask-migrate and Python in general so sorry if I use some wrong terminologies or if I am unaware of some methods.

After installation, it seems that flask-migrate automatically runs Python 2.7 rather than Python 3.7 which I installed.

I say that Python 2.7 is the issue because I got the following truncated error message:

```
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 906, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 569, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/kevin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
```

A Python 2.7 directory is loaded rather than a 3.x one. Later on in this error message I get a syntax error on a fstring which is new to Python 3.6 to my knowledge, so an outdated version of Python is definitely running.

I definitely have Python 3.7 installed on my Ubuntu system; this was some Terminal statements I ran earlier:

```
kevin@kevin-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:/$ cd home/kevin/.local/lib
kevin@kevin-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:~/.local/lib$ ls 
python2.7  python3.6  python3.7
```

I am also using Pycharm for this project, where I have a Python 3.7 interpreter running.

My project has worked in Python 3.7 until trying to install flask-migrate. I'd like to figure out how to install flask-migrate on my Ubuntu 18.04 system without having to run an outdated Python.

Comment: How did you install flask-migrate? Try `pip3 install Flask-Migrate` or `python3 -m pip install Flask-Migrate`.

Comment: I executed the first statement and it says all the requirements were satisfied; I tried the second statement but it says "no module named pip", will try to look into this, but it seems that I have the correct installation.

Comment: Huh? That shouldn't be right, as the former method usually calls the latter (although I guess since you have two instaces of python 3, things might be different). Try `which pip3` and `cat` the result.

Comment: Actually, try `which flask` and `cat` the result. We may be able to do a patch.

Comment: `which pip3` yields `/usr/local/bin/pip3` and `which flask` yields `/home/kevin/.local/bin/flask`.

Comment: Then `cat /usr/local/bin/pip3`; that is what I mean by "`cat` the result".

Comment: Result of  cat: `#!/usr/bin/python3.7

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())`

Comment: I guess your `python3` is Python 3.6 then... How about `cat /home/kevin/.local/bin/flask`?

Comment: Result of cat which flask `#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from flask.cli import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())`

Comment: Try using a text editor to change that `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3.7` and see if that fixes your problem.